# Quickly switch my phone between locked and unlocked without going through the menus?

Tags: applications, lock-screens, 7.0-nougat, automation, home-screen-shortcuts

I want to be able to quickly disable and enable Screen Lock, without having to manually go through `Settings -> Security -> Screen Lock` every time.

Is there a way to create a button on your home screen where, when you press it, it switches the screen lock from "Swipe" to "Pattern"?

Answer (score 0):

You can download macrodroid from the play store. I looked through it and you can use this to disable/enable the screenlock with a shortcut on the home screen. It is simple to use and you can probably figure it out yourself.

Comment: Is this possible to do with Tasker?

Comment: @SteveDolan I don't see why not